# How to pass slice into a function by reference

Tags: python, python-3.x, pass-by-reference, slice

If I have

```
a = [1, 2, 3]

def foo (arr):
    for i in len (arr): arr [i] += 1

def bar (arr):
    foo (arr[:2])

bar (a)
print (a)
```

I want output as

```
>>> [2, 3, 3 ]
```

How do I go about this?

Motivation: I want a priority queue where I can freeze last `N` elements, i.e. pass only `queue[:N]` to `heapq.heappush()`. But, every time I pass a slice, to it, or to any function in general, it sends a copy of slice and not the actual list to the function, and so my list remains unchanged in the end.

Comment: you have another problem: `for item in arr: item += 1` won't change the list either.

Comment: Making slice of array makes another object.

Comment: and what's the point of `arr[:2])` when output is `[2, 3, 4 ]` (adds 1 to all elements)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest instead of going for slice, I would just pass the indexes;

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
def foo(array, start, stop, jmp= 1):
    for idx in range(start, stop + 1, jmp):
        array[idx] += 1

def bar(array):
    foo(array, 1, 2)
bar(a)
print(a)
[1, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 5):

This will work if a is a `numpy` array. By default, `numpy` slices refer to the same block of memory as the original array.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1, 2, 3])

def foo(arr):
    for i in range(len(arr)): arr[i] += 1
    # or just arr += 1

def bar(arr):
    foo(arr[:2])

bar(a)
print(a)
# [2, 3, 3 ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a *list comprehension* and update the initial list using a full slice assignment with `[:]`:

```
def foo(arr):
   arr[:] = [x+1 for x in arr]
```

*Trial:*

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> def foo(arr):
...    arr[:] = [x+1 for x in arr]
...
>>> foo(a)
>>> a
[2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: nice but I think it does not the "slice" problem. I admit: the OP question is not clear but look at `def bar (arr):
    foo (arr[:2])`. I think it cannot be done that way.

Comment: I think the other function does not reflect the objective of the OP. I see their desired output was clearly stated

Answer (score 0):

*Slicing the list will create a new list with the sliced contents*, as such `arr[:2]` loses the reference to the original `a`.

Apart from that, iterating as you did won't change the list at all, it just changes an `item` and disregards the value.

If you want to alter specific parts of the list, you must carry with you a reference to the original list. For example, keep `arr`, iterate through a slice of it with `enumerate(arr[:2])` and then alter `arr`:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]

def foo(arr):
    for i, item in enumerate(arr[:2]): 
        arr[i] = item + 1

def bar(arr):
    foo(arr)

bar(a)
print(a)
```

Printing now yields `[2, 3, 3]`, removing the slice in `enumerate` results in `[2, 3, 4]`.  Of course, `bar` here serves no purpose, you could drop it and just keep `foo` and call `foo(a)` immediately.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre If the second problem is how to pass a slice and keep the original reference, then, it isn't possible in the way he wanted. You can slice during the iteration to achieve a similar result (if this is what he's after).